# Loading image file as a layer to Photoshop

Tags: python, python-3.x, photoshop

I have an existing PSD file that contains two images. My goal is to change one of the images to another image located in the same folder. I checked other questions and discovered that the same result can be achieved with Python in different ways, however I couldn't find the solution for my desired implementation. (I would like to do this by Photoshop's COM interface)

Actually, I can access to the layers and set their properties, but can't change the source image/object.

```
import win32com.client
import os

# opens ps
psApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Photoshop.Application")
# opens file
psApp.Open(r"F:\dev\ae\f1.psd") 

# new image to add
img1 = r"F:\dev\ae\img1.png"

doc = psApp.Application.ActiveDocument

# new blank layer
doc.ArtLayers.Add()

# get layer to change
layer = doc.ArtLayers[1]
```

[Adobe has scripting guides](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html) for various languages and I figured out that most of the method and property names in Python are based on the `VBScript version`, but I couldn't figure out the solution even [with the docs](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-vbs-ref-2019.pdf). When I call the `Add()` method on `ArtLayers` it creates a blank layer and I didn't find another method to do the same with an image/smartobject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey I was looking for the same thing and after digging through sample code in the docs you found, this is the work around I found.

```
psApp.Load(img1)
psApp.ActiveDocument.Selection.SelectAll()
psApp.ActiveDocument.Selection.Copy()
psApp.ActiveDocument.Close()
psApp.ActiveDocument.Paste()
```

I mean it is a bit stupid but it works. You might have to re-select the document you were on before pasting if it is not the last one.